# Pygame - transform.rotate results are using a lot of RAM

Tags: python, memory, pygame, ram

So, I'm making this little game where you have a flashlight. The flashlight is quite high resolution, so I need to precache 360 copies of it for every angle to avoid rotating it in realtime, which would take a lot of computing power. The image is 1002x246 and .png, but quite simple, so it only takes up 3.95KB on the hard drive. But when I make 360 copies of it in the game and add them to a list, they take around 800MB of RAM. That's quite a lot. Why? How can I reduce it?

The code:

```
def flashlightinit():
    init.flashlights = []
    fl = files.flashlight
    for i in range(360):
        init.flashlights.append(pygame.transform.rotate(fl, -i))
```

The flashlight image is convert()ed and doesn't have a colorkey or alpha-channel.

Displaying the flashlight:

```
def flashlightupdate(angle):
    screen.blit(init.flashlights[angle], (340 - init.flashlights[angle].get_width()/2, 360 - init.flashlights[angle].get_height()/2))
```

Angle is degrees and is calculated from mouse's position and from the player's position.

Thanks.

Comment: First, why do you need one picture for each 360th of a circle? How fine grained is going to be the "flashlight orientation control" for the player?

Comment: It needs to be as fine grained as possible, but the game currently has a low-res option which takes around 200MB of RAM, but then the game needs to transform.scale2x the low-res flashlight every frame. The flashlight rotates with mouse movement.

Comment: How many times are you calling `flashlightinit()`?

Comment: Making those copies was a panic solution to improve performance, so if there's any other way to do the job fast, it would be great.

Comment: flashlightinit() is being called only once, on startup.

Comment: The decoded bitmap size at 24bit per pixels is `360 x 1002 x 246 x 24 / 8` ~ 266MB of raw bitmap data.

Comment: As Dikei points out you have to take into account that, even if the file is small, you have 360 images, so the total size is 2 orders bigger. Also the file is probably a bit smaller than the object used to represent it in pygame, so a bitmap of X kb(as file) will occupy x+d kb in ram.
Maybe you should make less copies, and do call the rotation if the position of the flashlight is not in one of those you have cached.

Comment: You can make a list with rotations 0-90 degrees and calculate images for all other degrees with `pygame.transform.flip` on the fly http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip.

Comment: Great idea! I wonder how much faster `flip` is than `rotate`.

Comment: @ThexDLolNoob Please tell me about it when you tried.

Comment: After quick tests, flipping seems to be about 2-2.5 times faster than rotating, so it might work. Any suggestions on how to do the logic of getting the correct base image (0-90 degrees) to flip?

Comment: If you have your images for rotations 0° - 90° in an list `images` you can get it with the following pseudocode: `if degrees to rotate is between 0 - 90: index=degrees; else if degrees to rotate is between 91 - 180: index=180-degrees flip vertical; else if degrees to rotate is between 181 - 270: index=degrees-180 flip vertical and horizontal; else if degrees to rotate is between 271 - 360: index=360-degrees flip horizontal; rotated_image=images[index]`

Comment: Okay, I got it working, but it takes 4-8 milliseconds to flip and blit the flashlight, while with all precached it took only 1-2. That's four times slower, but still faster than rotating all the time. I think I'll revert back to precaching everything though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to publish this as an answer, since grouping together some of the comments you are probably going to solve both memory and performance issues.

The high RAM usage is due to the number of images (360), which, even on disk, would occupy *at least* 266MB, as Dikei pointed out, and you have to consider that images are represented as pygame objects, thus using more memory than a raw bitmap.

To avoid using 800MB of RAM you, obviously, have to avoid creating all those images.

To maintain good performances you could cache only some images for the degrees 0-90°,
and then use flip operations, which are quite faster than rotations, to build the images for the other rotation angles(as pointed out by halex).

In this way you can surely consume about 1/4 of current RAM and still have comparable rendering speed.

Comment: Flipping is still very slow, but those are all the options there is.

Comment: By they way, try to read [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/553/make-pygames-frame-rate-faster). Maybe some suggestions there might help you increase the speed.
Also, you may do some more caching[e.g. save other 30 positions, which are most used, or that were used most recently] to try avoiding unnecessary flips... but the impact on the performance depends a lot on how the object is rotating. If it's just rotating at random this wont help, if the rotations has some form of "locality", then caching some of the recent positions might help, but avoid caching too much.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have that many rotations, create a pyOpenGL rectangle, set the texture to your flashlight. Then rotate that.

You may use pygame for window creation/input , and pygame surfaces for OpenGL textures, or use Pyglet, or another solution.